# Process multiple files using apache camel

Tags: java, parallel-processing, apache-camel

I want to process multiple files using apache camel, tried with .thread method but not working as expected.

.thread(3) will pick multiple files and process but if thread1 process first then immediately it will not go for file4 instead it's waiting all threads( remaining 2 threads) to complete process

**Update:**

```
 from("file:filepath?maxMessagesPerPoll=1&delete=true&readLockMinLength=0")
.routeId("gateway.msg2file.cnqm1")
.threads(3,3) 
.process(myProcessor)
.choice()
  .when(header("Result").isEqualTo(true))
     .to("path") .otherwise()
     .to("file://xxx")
     .setBody( simple("test"))
     .setHeader("sss"))
     .to("velocity:testmail.vm")
     .to("smtp://test@mail.com"+ "&contentType=" + "text/html");
```

Comment: from("file:filepath?maxMessagesPerPoll=1&delete=true&readLockMinLength=0")
    .routeId("testroute")    
                .threads(3,3) 
    .process(myProcessor)
    .choice()
    .when(header("Result").isEqualTo(true))
    .to("path")
    .otherwise()
    .to("file://xxx")
    .setBody(
      simple("test"))
    .setHeader("sss"))
    .to("velocity:testmail.vm")
    .to("smtp://test@mail.com"+ "&contentType=" + "text/html");

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai, Please find above comment for route source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from("file:filepath?maxMessagesPerPoll=1&delete=true&readLockMinLength=0")
.to("seda:input");

from("seda:input?concurrentConsumers=3")
.process(myProcessor)
.choice()
 .when(header("Result").isEqualTo(true))
    .to("path") .otherwise()
    .to("file://xxx")
    .setBody( simple("test"))
    .setHeader("sss"))
    .to("velocity:testmail.vm")
    .to("smtp://test@mail.com"+ "&contentType=" + "text/html");
```

Comment: Using SEDA is recommended as you have better control on thread creation and management

Comment: Hi, I have a case that I need to process 200k files with Apache Camel, parse them and save in my database, do you have any tip for what is the best approach that I could use for that? Thanks in advance.